# Describe the possible echelon forms for matrices with the following properties

Tags: linear-algebra

> Describe the possible echelon forms for matrices with the following properties
>
> $a) A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix with linearly dependent columns
>
> $b) A$ is a $4 \times 3$ matrix, $A = [\vec{a_1} \vec{a_2} \vec{a_3}]$ such that ${\{ \vec{a_1} \vec{a_2}\} }$ is linearly independent and $\vec{a_3}$ is not in the span of $\vec{a_1}$ and $\vec{a_2}$

I'm not really sure how to answer these. What I'm thinking is that for $a)$- a $2 \times 2$ matrix with linearly dependent columns could mean that all of the **pivots = 0** or that the $det(A) = 0$  ? I'm not quite sure.

for $b)$ - I honestly have no clue , any help would be great

**UPDATE:**

$a)$ The columns of the 2x2 matrix could $\textbf{not}$ have the form $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ because as long as it has only the trivial solution and 2 basic variables so would mean that **linearly independent** so for it to be linearly dependent it would need to be a matrix of all **0**'s or a matrix of at least one free variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Part a)}$ Two vectors are linearly dependent if and only if one is a scalar multiple of the other.

So in a)

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & ca \\
b & cb
\end{pmatrix}$$

There are some cases: If both $a,b=0$, then $A$ is the zero matrix and that is its reduced row echelon.

If $a\neq 0$ or $b\neq 0$, then the reduced row echelon form of this matrix is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & c \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}_.$$

$\textbf{Part b)}$ The conditions give that $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are linearly independent. Therefore the rank of the matrix is $3$ and the rref is:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}_.$$